# How can I pass variables from JS to JSX?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have this **function** into my **JS** file...

```
function get_HexForegroundColor()
{
    var chosenFunction = 'pickHexForegroundColor()';
    csInterface.evalScript(chosenFunction, function(result)
    {
        hexForegroundColor = result;
        // etc...
    });
};
```

which get a **value** from this **function** in **JSX** file.

```
function pickHexForegroundColor()
{
    var decimal_Color = app.foregroundColor.rgb.hexValue;
    var hexadecimal_Color = decimal_Color.toString(16);
    return [hexadecimal_Color];             
};
```

For some reasons I want to **pass** a **variable** from **JS** to **JSX**. In my case, how can I do that?

Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: can't you just write ```'pixHexForegroundColor(5)'``` for instance (if you want to give 5 as a variable?)

Comment: @user753642 I am new to all this but it was so easy... Thank you very much and sorry for this stupid question!!! This happens when mind is out of order because of fatigue.